# ERROR in The loader in .scss didn't return a string after upgrade cli version 7.3.6

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc

I upgraded my project by using `ng update` getting below error when in run `ng build --prod`

> ERROR in The loader "...\ClientApp\src\app\nav-menu\nav-menu.component.scss" didn't return a string.

Below are my package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "7.2.11",
"@angular/cdk": "7.3.6",
"@angular/common": "7.2.11",
"@angular/compiler": "7.2.11",
"@angular/core": "7.2.11",
"@angular/forms": "7.2.11",
"@angular/http": "7.2.11",
"@angular/material": "7.3.6",
"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "7.3.6",
"@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.11",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.11",
"@angular/platform-server": "7.2.11",
"@angular/router": "7.2.11",
"@aspnet/signalr": "1.1.2",
"@ng-idle/core": "^6.0.0-beta.4",
"@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^7.1.1",
"aspnet-prerendering": "3.0.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
"bootstrap4-datetimepicker": "^5.2.3",
"core-js": "^2.6.5",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"highcharts": "6.1.4",
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"node-sass": "^4.11.0",
"primeng": "^7.1.0",
"rxjs": "^6.4.0",
"zone.js": "^0.9.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.13.6",
"@angular/cli": "7.3.6",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "",
"@angular/language-service": "7.2.11",
"@types/jasmine": "^3.3.12",
"@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
"@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
"@types/node": "^11.12.0",
"codelyzer": "5.0.0-beta.2",
"jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "^4.0.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
"karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
"keycloak-angular": "^6.1.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.11",
"ng2-bootstrap-modal": "https://github.com/Sky4CE/ng2-bootstrap-modal/tarball/v.1.0.2",
"npm-font-open-sans": "^1.1.0",
"popper.js": "^1.14.7",
"preboot": "7.0.0",
"protractor": "^6.0.0",
"raw-loader": "2.0.0",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.13",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.4.0",
"stacktrace-js": "^2.0.0",
"ts-node": "~8.0.3",
"tslint": "~5.14.0",
"typescript": "^3.2.4",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.1.0",
"css-to-string-loader": "^0.1.3"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem with "raw-loader": "2.0.0", try downgrade version of raw-loader to '1.0.0'

Comment: Yes, that's what the problem was. Figured it out after lot of banging